# How can I block direct access to images in a directory but allow PHP to display them?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
```

But when I display the images I'm just putting a link to the image in an  tag, but the images are not showing up.

How can I display the image but disallow direct access to it? Is there a way for me to just copy the raw bytes of the file and display them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be sure to save *embedded.png* in same folder as this example source.

```
<?php
function data_uri($file, $mime) 
{  
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  $base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
  return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
?>

<html>
    <h1>Embedded Image:-</h1>
    <img src="<?php echo data_uri('embedded.png','image/png'); ?>" alt="Embedded image" />
</html>
```

Comment: no problem, advantage of this is that you can store images in real production system out of server path, thus the images are only available embedded. (or block all .png files for same effect).

Answer (score 0):

Send the appropriate `Content-Type` header for the image, and then use [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to stream the bytes to output.

Also, if you're going to use a filepath in the URL for this, be certain to sanitize the filepath first so that e.g. `/etc/passwd` can't be read using your script.